# Error when batch persisting

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I'm trying to perform what seems to me to be a simple process with Doctrine, however I keep getting an error

**Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column (column_label) VALUES ('Asset')'**

I'm failing to see where I've gone wrong, would anyone be able to point it out to me

```
$columnLabels[0] = "Asset";
$columnLabels[1] = "Number Of Unit";
$columnLabels[2] = "Uptime";
$columnLabels[3] = "Standby";
$columnLabels[4] = "Downtime";
$columnLabels[5] = "Consumption";
$columnLabels[6] = "Co2 Emissions";
$columnLabels[7] = "Total Cost";

for( $i = 0; $i < count($columnLabels); $i++ ){
    $column = new Column();
    $column->setColumnLabel( $columnLabels[$i] );
    $entityManager->persist($column);
}

$entityManager->flush();
$entityManager->clear();

$entityManager->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());
```

Thanks, Caius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

column can't be used as a table name in SQL